cssのpositionにstickyを設定したが、緑色のボックスが動かない
positionにstickyを選択したのですが、画像のRelative以下の緑色のボックスが動きません。
Google Chromeを使用しています。

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #3d405b;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.middle {
    background-color: #81b29a;
}

#static .middle {
    top: 100px;
    position: static;
}

#relative .middle {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Position Property</h1>
    <section id="static">
        <h2>Static</h2>
        <div></div>
        <div class="middle"></div>
        <div></div>
    </section>

    <section id="relative">
        <h2>Rerative</h2>
        <div></div>
        <div class="middle"></div>
        <div></div>
    </section>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis atque, repudiandae nobis doloremque veritatis ad voluptatem quisquam repellendus nam, nostrum aut quo. Suscipit consequatur dolorum, officiis aspernatur asperiores corrupti excepturi!
    Fuga earum eveniet molestiae ipsa. Quisquam sapiente nam quod temporibus adipisci earum, incidunt facere similique voluptatibus quia rem officia pariatur ducimus eaque a cupiditate. Minima blanditiis quis consectetur sed repudiandae.
    Sapiente inventore sint animi. Excepturi, explicabo porro? Cupiditate inventore minima sint consequatur voluptate obcaecati voluptatibus! Fugit quis voluptas atque, praesentium ut numquam, eveniet impedit reiciendis magnam assumenda recusandae et quas.
    Rem aut dicta eveniet consectetur, corrupti, nisi sunt dignissimos libero totam, quaerat vel quo. Tempora modi in quae dolor, neque, adipisci perspiciatis provident minus hic, a numquam repudiandae dignissimos sapiente!
    Accusamus, dignissimos alias eius, obcaecati mollitia, laborum ad recusandae assumenda possimus quam sed odio eveniet blanditiis. Laborum dicta aperiam ex sapiente error provident aliquam, et molestias explicabo natus, aspernatur aut?
    Accusantium, dolor alias, cupiditate nam laboriosam veniam ducimus optio ipsam odio quaerat, consequatur perspiciatis ad nostrum ullam dignissimos! Veniam repellat, molestias temporibus quia voluptatibus optio deleniti nemo culpa vero ab?
    Ipsa mollitia obcaecati similique? Possimus amet et commodi, aspernatur, reprehenderit officia debitis illo alias nobis veritatis cupiditate voluptate fugit corporis sit accusantium praesentium porro, consequatur aliquam sint reiciendis voluptatibus! Neque.
    Consequatur quis a eum ratione impedit, quas libero maiores molestiae magni natus laborum adipisci numquam! Incidunt repellendus repellat unde labore deserunt neque laborum libero! Rerum consequatur debitis facilis reprehenderit mollitia!
    Sapiente laborum neque excepturi, sunt dolorem eum aperiam, provident laboriosam ipsum atque magni nemo delectus reprehenderit maxime amet quos nostrum. Eligendi accusamus excepturi minima odit eos cupiditate officia repudiandae qui.
    Repellat asperiores corrupti deserunt itaque architecto dolore sint quaerat similique veritatis cumque error ipsam voluptatibus perferendis excepturi, voluptas unde dolores? Dolores expedita illo qui, reprehenderit nihil quae ad? Dicta, consequuntur!
    Enim voluptatem non adipisci ab fugiat distinctio. Maiores cum unde nam repudiandae quidem, labore, tempora asperiores veniam ut aliquid hic quibusdam inventore provident dolores! Est repellendus quibusdam sed odit aliquid?
    Repellat excepturi rem voluptate hic dolores eaque asperiores aspernatur quisquam nam ipsam perspiciatis voluptatem adipisci veniam, dolorem suscipit alias id harum ipsum aliquam officia. Soluta quam consectetur rem! Accusantium, non?
    Placeat labore necessitatibus voluptatibus dolore at dignissimos reiciendis, quam dicta consectetur autem voluptatem quos minima quibusdam! Exercitationem quos commodi porro earum qui ad repellat enim facilis, reprehenderit velit dolorum veritatis.
    Illum vel officiis a perspiciatis aperiam, labore quaerat ea ipsum odit voluptatum hic totam aspernatur illo laborum iure? Id ratione molestiae eos incidunt dolor quasi velit ipsum quaerat cupiditate nisi?
    Voluptatem odio nam, impedit deleniti iure itaque nulla distinctio. Perspiciatis vitae, aliquid consectetur aliquam dolores velit ipsa minima quam eligendi fuga reprehenderit cupiditate? Reiciendis harum esse cumque illo maxime dolor!
    Dolorum iusto pariatur omnis fuga, repellendus voluptatum architecto nam debitis. Quae nesciunt ex quisquam veritatis nisi quidem voluptas atque eius sit temporibus blanditiis laboriosam quam dignissimos beatae, recusandae quibusdam at.
    Assumenda maiores sed inventore libero, facere enim porro accusamus harum odio voluptatibus magni deleniti dolor nisi debitis ipsum delectus commodi, sequi officia fugiat! Officiis reprehenderit ipsum facilis esse dolorum aspernatur!
    Quidem eum eius ipsam voluptas ab perferendis voluptate incidunt hic voluptatibus, fugit distinctio illum consequuntur provident ratione saepe molestiae. Ipsam temporibus labore perferendis sed facere esse voluptatibus modi soluta ipsum.
    Sunt vel similique reprehenderit velit facere, vero optio ipsa nisi itaque aut nobis perferendis provident saepe, tempora, hic sapiente iste repellendus quia iure officia fugiat! Similique reprehenderit eligendi temporibus sint.
    Accusantium libero quisquam unde. Perspiciatis quas quos voluptatem labore? Hic natus, distinctio et eius dolor dolore saepe magnam ipsa est ab illum accusamus architecto. Officia omnis veritatis nam exercitationem voluptatibus!
    Illo beatae nihil perspiciatis, impedit architecto dolore quae velit eveniet eligendi tempore et expedita sed accusantium aliquid maxime eos unde doloremque! Numquam a est eaque, repellendus assumenda accusamus reprehenderit consectetur.
    Ipsa voluptatibus deleniti et temporibus obcaecati numquam quia, fuga atque, labore quis adipisci ut? At voluptate, asperiores est sint nulla ad repudiandae aspernatur. Natus fugiat fugit dolores eius, deleniti consectetur.
    Unde nostrum repudiandae magnam, fugiat iusto illum illo saepe officiis odit ut eos architecto similique tenetur molestias maxime eaque, temporibus voluptatem, obcaecati eum! Voluptas, saepe inventore quos tenetur officiis minima.
    Ipsam vel dolore, laborum a fugit eligendi nihil sunt, repudiandae incidunt dolorem labore rerum harum culpa enim. Aliquam perferendis consequatur voluptates rerum cum magnam! Consectetur sunt dicta pariatur nisi repudiandae?
    Nisi dicta debitis ipsa, voluptatum odit cumque! Laudantium, laborum quia in optio doloremque soluta provident temporibus ut deserunt est quo vitae ratione, explicabo eveniet accusantium cumque dolores et blanditiis quae?
    Officia minus suscipit, unde mollitia cupiditate tempore ullam quis, libero sit earum eius explicabo, corporis asperiores? Beatae sint quidem incidunt assumenda, culpa mollitia temporibus quos, dolorem eos harum fugiat tempora.
    Nulla, ab. Natus voluptates illum, facilis voluptas assumenda architecto adipisci blanditiis iusto dolor impedit beatae suscipit non obcaecati voluptatibus. Quisquam explicabo nisi expedita molestias labore, nam quos? Veniam, iusto fugit?
    Nobis commodi eveniet odio ex eius sapiente cumque assumenda nam impedit error hic nisi quas nihil soluta alias enim, harum, aperiam voluptas eaque laudantium sint non animi quod ab! Quas.
    Autem blanditiis exercitationem voluptatem nulla mollitia quisquam quaerat! Ea repellat quas laboriosam velit iure, distinctio enim, corporis ex vitae ipsam quae necessitatibus totam sed consequuntur possimus atque fuga explicabo. Odio!
    A ipsum odio temporibus! Eius expedita nemo tempore suscipit illum magni fugiat enim doloremque omnis sit corporis, quo voluptatem iusto cupiditate quas autem rerum! Non ab quos temporibus alias eveniet?
    Ratione inventore hic aliquam tempore rem culpa recusandae repudiandae deleniti totam, quae aperiam voluptas nostrum nobis iure nihil rerum vitae dolor in, impedit dicta itaque mollitia eligendi fuga magnam! Itaque.
    Distinctio consectetur voluptates quisquam atque totam officiis fuga magnam quam iste facilis laborum eaque autem libero numquam alias beatae, error, similique temporibus id quos incidunt. Ad voluptatibus qui voluptates eligendi.
    Possimus, consectetur iure, quos recusandae eos obcaecati impedit incidunt odit reiciendis sequi, repellat error? Id, saepe? Recusandae corporis magni, saepe perferendis aut quod, magnam id error quaerat molestiae nam iste.
    Debitis, omnis aspernatur. Id provident inventore illum rem deserunt vitae molestiae quibusdam soluta repellat doloremque! Exercitationem tenetur est corrupti similique, voluptatibus sunt libero odit doloribus, quae nemo tempora facere quidem.
    Optio cumque facere ad facilis quo. Tempore voluptates, soluta nihil repellendus fugiat distinctio corrupti temporibus voluptatibus ex asperiores dolorem cumque minus labore dolor nam possimus odit aliquam numquam! Et, sint.
    Officiis quae rem unde deserunt minima, autem aut id harum nulla sint maiores sit non illum libero repellendus provident doloremque, at ipsa repudiandae sunt sapiente totam pariatur earum? Vitae, iste?
    Qui, dignissimos ex aspernatur eligendi, minus vel, ipsum quia nulla non minima odit eveniet sunt sapiente quae commodi. Illo error dicta optio provident, omnis sequi ad nobis odio repudiandae quas.
    Rerum veritatis voluptatum vero, repellat molestias perferendis totam eligendi culpa et amet nulla dicta omnis similique perspiciatis mollitia maiores. Quas vel nemo recusandae, aut libero nostrum! Nam natus quasi harum.
    Consectetur, qui at laboriosam incidunt rem est veritatis sequi debitis commodi cumque. Quis sequi magnam facere vel, officia itaque excepturi ex aliquam. Deleniti culpa unde a voluptatibus odit sequi animi?
    Alias maiores nobis in esse obcaecati! Nam quae alias minus! Veniam quidem consequuntur necessitatibus recusandae corporis adipisci nobis doloremque minima, corrupti cupiditate soluta inventore placeat laboriosam ipsum rerum mollitia sunt.
    Perspiciatis aperiam reiciendis corporis soluta nesciunt similique repellendus doloribus nihil! Labore quia quidem at architecto ad, nihil necessitatibus qui perspiciatis laborum soluta molestias, tempore assumenda saepe eos, cumque recusandae distinctio.
    Enim officiis cumque itaque rerum qui consequuntur ipsum officia modi voluptatibus quibusdam distinctio alias ad sunt numquam temporibus, ab iusto repellat molestiae sed quia velit expedita dignissimos? Animi, nostrum repellat?
    Temporibus quibusdam, dignissimos asperiores veritatis maiores, ipsa architecto veniam perspiciatis ducimus impedit facilis itaque aperiam sint dolore nostrum soluta repellat quia esse ea consectetur optio? Dolorum obcaecati doloremque ut dolore?
    Aperiam veritatis pariatur asperiores nobis, adipisci aspernatur hic voluptate numquam ex dolores delectus cumque eligendi quos vel repudiandae vero qui ipsa voluptatem ea quam? Porro in a nisi suscipit expedita.
    A laborum praesentium architecto magni eum fuga nulla, fugit ullam voluptatibus. Deleniti consequatur ullam, sint eaque, praesentium temporibus voluptatum maiores mollitia adipisci, incidunt soluta ipsam pariatur rem! Repudiandae, corrupti tempore.
    Ipsum nemo ad est iste dolorum et excepturi deserunt, culpa, nisi accusamus nulla similique facere explicabo voluptatem reprehenderit quae. Molestiae veniam at quis voluptatibus, delectus esse inventore itaque. Quae, magnam.
    Id, asperiores placeat. In nemo aspernatur modi suscipit consequatur consectetur qui illum minima velit! Mollitia reiciendis, consectetur dolor repellendus a dolorum eum neque eveniet quas beatae reprehenderit, sapiente ipsa in?
    Assumenda dolores repudiandae neque iste ea delectus exercitationem quas omnis, ut, ipsam illum placeat ex odit, possimus quos? Quam debitis nesciunt nulla voluptas blanditiis reprehenderit. Accusamus placeat sed quos modi.
    Beatae, a molestiae officiis provident sunt eveniet placeat, ullam, deleniti itaque cupiditate esse ipsa perferendis minus voluptatem? Beatae accusamus inventore vero voluptatum ea ad quibusdam, quo sapiente, perspiciatis eligendi rem.
    Voluptatem possimus necessitatibus reprehenderit ea ab repellat, illum accusamus dolorum odit assumenda, dolor cumque doloremque consequatur quo veritatis numquam nesciunt alias officia corporis incidunt. In pariatur quisquam repellendus rem tempore.
    Iusto ipsam nisi enim qui quos distinctio optio et numquam dignissimos pariatur sapiente repudiandae perferendis nemo, voluptatum hic sunt at officiis error a neque maxime natus. Facilis minus quaerat molestiae.
    Voluptatum aliquam, modi nesciunt iure exercitationem aliquid totam, dolor assumenda porro aut quae similique, iste eius repudiandae nobis? Nesciunt ut harum doloribus architecto nihil obcaecati distinctio nisi molestiae a impedit.
    Delectus dicta expedita consequatur hic odit id nam facere perspiciatis earum error ipsum possimus numquam facilis nobis voluptates quaerat, ullam, voluptatum architecto quos natus, exercitationem tempora? Quisquam incidunt iure necessitatibus.
    Dolorum debitis quidem vero, tempora obcaecati cumque totam rerum ea id aut ad molestiae cum nisi mollitia natus nam fuga repudiandae. Recusandae, dolorum nesciunt? Id vitae quos asperiores! Provident, similique.
    Nemo asperiores ratione corporis, odit non dolorem velit optio! Consectetur iste ipsa quo suscipit omnis exercitationem, eaque repudiandae nostrum voluptatem, necessitatibus provident. Laboriosam voluptates ipsa, quibusdam nobis sed architecto aliquid!
    Nulla obcaecati velit voluptatem itaque sequi odit dolores esse nisi iusto laudantium, quis tenetur nostrum repudiandae atque libero corrupti fugiat, sed molestias. Nisi, praesentium. Eveniet earum dicta ipsam porro magni?
    Alias, deleniti, culpa, tempore nihil consectetur sit pariatur harum cum quas impedit iste. Nemo sapiente suscipit fugiat magni facilis maxime, laborum asperiores, modi quas sed nobis vel ut sequi. Aut?
    Error provident hic corporis molestias similique accusantium autem incidunt optio distinctio temporibus itaque, voluptas sapiente expedita suscipit possimus deleniti ipsa labore voluptates nobis at? Ex porro delectus excepturi deleniti assumenda?
    Ipsum, et amet. Praesentium vero quas minima ad! Ex similique, deserunt, incidunt molestiae veniam, iusto ipsa sequi magni a quam reprehenderit necessitatibus odio temporibus dolorum exercitationem at voluptatibus deleniti debitis.
    Deserunt alias fugit fugiat molestias iusto consequatur corporis, facere id, accusamus ad debitis? Magnam quisquam porro quae, atque, exercitationem nihil quaerat quam voluptatum animi corrupti magni mollitia nesciunt, sit eveniet?
    Illo sint quo in, suscipit quaerat numquam molestiae quasi blanditiis porro. Quae hic explicabo odio voluptatibus quam incidunt quidem facere error, laboriosam magnam! Sapiente est consequatur quae nemo possimus distinctio.
    Neque eligendi omnis maxime accusamus repellat, ut praesentium, voluptas quos velit harum labore quae hic eaque pariatur, expedita assumenda distinctio. Quasi, est? Corporis magni aut quibusdam eveniet dolore! Voluptates, facilis.
    Laborum iste eius cum tenetur minima qui dolore libero. Unde possimus doloremque velit aliquid minima tenetur quae perspiciatis in? Vero perferendis illum nostrum perspiciatis, exercitationem accusantium voluptates quae quibusdam officiis.
    Accusamus tempora beatae suscipit qui, dolores asperiores nam commodi temporibus totam sequi libero, sapiente eum, quibusdam nobis cupiditate. Magnam vel deleniti rerum quod perferendis, atque eveniet soluta! Omnis, dolorem ducimus.
    Natus iste libero pariatur accusantium fuga nihil, illo consectetur in illum officia beatae quos ad minus et repellat blanditiis consequatur numquam quo voluptatibus quae possimus quam? Accusamus deserunt voluptate eligendi.
    Nesciunt nobis placeat unde fugiat consectetur? Voluptatibus eos corporis perferendis adipisci ab ipsa illo at, quam temporibus, totam minus aliquam quas vel. Hic perferendis, nostrum maiores accusantium quam animi porro?
    Harum animi hic voluptatibus recusandae quisquam culpa vero consectetur, sit explicabo dolor iure eaque in id eligendi consequuntur et. Qui id et recusandae, autem aliquam consequatur cum aliquid sit? Consequatur.
    Delectus repellendus quisquam esse impedit minima quod dolor consectetur beatae optio et nam quae amet hic suscipit consequuntur, laboriosam illum recusandae voluptatibus eum illo assumenda dolorem laborum adipisci inventore. Placeat!
    Totam laborum magnam animi omnis soluta, natus sint dolorum voluptates maxime exercitationem voluptatum vel quidem officiis, molestiae eos eum ab aliquam ipsum commodi rerum nisi recusandae error inventore illo. Quas!
    Quibusdam animi, soluta, labore dolorem quas, ipsum corrupti iste provident eum et asperiores error perferendis quisquam esse amet non praesentium necessitatibus laboriosam voluptate! Optio cumque hic corrupti atque ducimus incidunt!
    Natus ut qui, ea aut quas molestiae debitis obcaecati blanditiis voluptates excepturi quam? Iste libero quo culpa reiciendis ad consequuntur temporibus neque deleniti, cumque voluptatum quos dolores ullam, officia delectus.
    Nobis sint voluptate molestias, perspiciatis delectus accusantium unde voluptatibus rem, eum saepe dolore nam dolor, corrupti error corporis ad beatae maxime! Nisi aspernatur esse possimus recusandae odit, harum aperiam fugiat?
    Possimus molestias ex sequi at, quas minus id unde consequatur adipisci hic voluptatem perferendis ea provident magni quia voluptates necessitatibus? Rem consectetur perspiciatis recusandae pariatur, voluptates soluta est natus libero!
    Ducimus vero eum vel, id aut eius quis tempore libero nisi. Earum aut cumque corporis sint quasi ratione iure eligendi rerum unde. Tempore, facere quod aut temporibus dicta at aspernatur?
    Nesciunt consectetur pariatur, minus quos repellendus corrupti ratione voluptatum perspiciatis soluta, corporis mollitia temporibus ab accusamus dignissimos unde aliquam veritatis suscipit? Ipsum doloremque praesentium minima assumenda blanditiis molestias veritatis iure.
    Quo modi perspiciatis itaque fuga incidunt ut doloremque magnam quisquam corrupti voluptas asperiores aliquid nobis at, ex accusantium possimus quaerat culpa illum earum eius quod! Nemo cupiditate aspernatur laboriosam vero.
    Aliquam distinctio sed eum est dolores officia repellendus fugiat accusamus. Commodi ullam doloremque ex aliquam esse qui, voluptatem laboriosam voluptates soluta ab. Laudantium culpa voluptate ipsa nostrum beatae ipsum nobis?
    Autem sapiente ullam repellat ut sequi rerum illo. Labore maxime fugiat fuga perferendis quo veritatis asperiores dicta id porro odio voluptatem, et provident? Labore eos corporis nisi pariatur quam voluptatem!
    At sit, eum ullam aliquid ipsum inventore maiores voluptatum eligendi. Maxime sunt provident aperiam aut officia quod natus earum tempora quos cupiditate modi necessitatibus atque eaque, distinctio voluptatibus assumenda deleniti.
    Consequuntur eveniet quaerat cupiditate natus nostrum! Quis minus quidem, nobis eligendi ducimus possimus voluptatibus beatae reiciendis harum numquam, sit modi error eius, omnis similique. Voluptas sunt a sapiente! Labore, earum.
    Vitae doloremque fugit quibusdam dolorem expedita consequuntur eum labore libero magnam. Nemo debitis cum, veniam impedit, at culpa aliquam velit quidem placeat non iure asperiores ipsa sit officia accusamus laborum?
    Quis odit eveniet cum aut animi. Deserunt reiciendis rem consequuntur? Deleniti saepe vero totam recusandae corporis hic temporibus, ipsa ipsum eius officiis corrupti fugiat quasi consectetur eveniet voluptas. Placeat, est.
    Fugit laudantium veniam corrupti laboriosam officiis numquam quos porro illum, eveniet doloremque molestiae nesciunt recusandae ad unde sapiente minima magni ducimus culpa itaque deserunt. Excepturi laudantium voluptatem fuga voluptas reiciendis.
    Nostrum corporis ipsa repellendus autem expedita eius nihil totam inventore maxime. Natus, sapiente. Neque perspiciatis aliquam ab voluptates rerum provident assumenda expedita sed alias? Reprehenderit, voluptatibus nihil! Ipsam, a voluptatum!
    Dolorem veniam rem similique aliquid esse nobis architecto quae? Fuga sequi iure debitis molestias veritatis! Quibusdam aspernatur ducimus reiciendis! Similique id tenetur iusto! Qui sed cupiditate quod doloribus perferendis veniam.
    Quaerat cum molestiae unde porro illo quia ipsum iusto! Nisi dolor laborum itaque excepturi veritatis modi culpa, nihil amet fuga, temporibus blanditiis, maiores magnam. Facere eius ratione nisi a omnis?
    Numquam sequi nulla maxime nihil id enim vel quis non consectetur similique nisi asperiores reiciendis quae eligendi debitis fugit, quo aliquid beatae magni sapiente totam obcaecati! Ea temporibus voluptatum atque.
    Eaque rerum quam veniam quisquam ducimus, voluptatum quod. Vero numquam sint repellat impedit ipsa magni laudantium praesentium veniam hic assumenda atque itaque reiciendis ex quia eum quisquam, vitae asperiores repudiandae.
    Optio beatae perferendis harum unde eius libero quidem consequuntur incidunt facere. Quas voluptatem similique dicta ab, ut quibusdam excepturi totam reiciendis odio, consectetur voluptatum beatae harum! Molestias ratione nemo doloremque.
    Consequatur repellat laborum voluptatibus molestias veritatis ex, distinctio similique aut soluta quam maxime possimus. Itaque quidem molestiae placeat possimus facilis et dolor vitae deserunt ab doloremque laboriosam fuga, iure optio?
    Praesentium ipsam nostrum suscipit aperiam nesciunt molestiae odit, asperiores facilis voluptates reprehenderit libero alias magnam eos perspiciatis similique, error quam laboriosam dicta sit pariatur corporis numquam. In fugiat necessitatibus voluptatem?
    Rem, necessitatibus voluptatum quas natus voluptas explicabo, provident suscipit saepe id laudantium sapiente! Aliquam dicta laborum voluptatibus alias quis maxime, recusandae minus ea accusantium dolore, sint odio sit saepe nesciunt!
    Dolor expedita blanditiis officiis eligendi error. Ex minus accusantium reiciendis veritatis ad sed atque omnis deserunt sapiente odit est, esse eos provident corrupti temporibus quo optio voluptatem fugit? Perspiciatis, officiis!
    Provident, itaque consequuntur quis perferendis ipsam alias tempore quibusdam quas esse. Exercitationem unde autem eaque tempora, iste quae dolores cum dolorem eos! Sequi et tenetur reiciendis eveniet eaque aliquid corporis.
    Labore repellat modi facilis quos a explicabo aliquam neque, nam suscipit accusamus temporibus. Unde distinctio quisquam, enim asperiores error reprehenderit tenetur repellendus minima? Repellendus animi asperiores voluptates, nam consequuntur saepe!
    Omnis quam qui aut temporibus fuga possimus, obcaecati odio animi amet eum recusandae minus quae assumenda, expedita inventore eligendi. Voluptatem labore ex eius qui dolores omnis placeat hic! Quis, obcaecati?
    Sapiente fugiat neque, vero mollitia voluptate impedit nam perspiciatis magnam adipisci! Similique libero earum aliquid consequatur laborum. Eligendi libero iure ipsum ullam illo excepturi dolorum alias quasi recusandae dignissimos. Suscipit.
    Consectetur a qui, molestiae corrupti deserunt quaerat porro similique? Cupiditate, quos fugiat consectetur magnam placeat iure deleniti magni! Dicta sed itaque omnis aut facere harum voluptate veritatis in eius eos?
    Iure harum, consequatur nobis aliquam rem velit nisi, in perspiciatis ab blanditiis ipsam dignissimos ullam quos corrupti perferendis voluptatum iusto praesentium tempore nesciunt sunt ratione corporis quam optio? Sapiente, assumenda?
    Et ex voluptatem repudiandae veritatis totam cupiditate nemo exercitationem quod architecto necessitatibus tenetur maiores modi reprehenderit molestiae velit porro quaerat id, qui inventore eos temporibus dignissimos facere beatae accusantium? Cupiditate.
</body>
</html>



「動かない」とはどういうことか説明してください。  https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/position にデモがありますが、それとどう違うのですか？

仕様どおり#relativeの中でstick動作すると思います。質問者さんはどういう動作を期待していたのでしょうか。

言葉足らずで申し訳ありません。
スクロールを行っても、#relativeの緑色のブロックがstick動作をせず、そのまま見切れてしまいます。

#relativeが画面外に行っても緑ブロックが画面内に残ることを期待していますか?

はい。画面内に残る動作を期待しています。


スクロールを行っても、#relativeの緑色のブロックがstick動作をせず、そのまま見切れてしまいます。

問題は、上の質問に対する私のコメントで紹介した MDN の記事 position のデモ「試してみましょう」で以下のようにならず、そのままスクロールされて隠れてしまうということと理解します。

MDN の記事に "「スクロールの仕組み」を持つ直近の祖先（overflow が hidden, scroll, auto, overlay として作成されたもの）に「粘着」します。" と書いてあります。
質問者さんのコードで直近の祖先は section になるはずですが、それが「overflow が hidden, scroll, auto, overlay として作成」されてないのが原因だと思われます。
以下のように section で囲む部分を広げて、style="height: 500px; width: 500px; overflow: auto;" を追加して試してみてください。
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #3d405b;
            border: 2px solid black;
            margin: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .middle {
            background-color: #81b29a;
        }

        #static .middle {
            top: 100px;
            position: static;
        }

        #relative .middle {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Position Property</h1>

    <section id="relative" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; overflow: auto;">
        <h2>Relative</h2>
        <div></div>
        <div class="middle"></div>
        <div></div>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis atque, repudiandae nobis doloremque veritatis ad voluptatem quisquam repellendus nam, nostrum aut quo. Suscipit consequatur dolorum, officiis aspernatur asperiores corrupti excepturi!
    Fuga earum eveniet molestiae ipsa. Quisquam sapiente nam quod temporibus adipisci earum, incidunt facere similique voluptatibus quia rem officia pariatur ducimus eaque a cupiditate. Minima blanditiis quis consectetur sed repudiandae.
    Sapiente inventore sint animi. Excepturi, explicabo porro? Cupiditate inventore minima sint consequatur voluptate obcaecati voluptatibus! Fugit quis voluptas atque, praesentium ut numquam, eveniet impedit reiciendis magnam assumenda recusandae et quas.

            ・・・略・・・
        </p>

    </section>
</body>
</html>

結果は以下のようになるはずです。

